# Parse json into a series of documents in a collection using a for or foreach loop best? [meteor]

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app that pulls data in from an external api. For simplicity sake we'll say something like...

```
var foo = Meteor.http.call("GET", "api-endpoint-url-here");
```

And inserts the data into a collection...

```
    Bar = new Mongo.Collection("bar");
    Bar.insert({
      Results: foo
    });
```

The json array (e.g. foo) includes a number of individual records each of which has it's own id number and corresponding data. I'm presently using JSON.parse to establish my array and then looping through the array to create individual documents using _.each

```
 var fooParsed = JSON.parse(foo.content)
 var fooArray = fooParsed.results;
 _.each(fooArray, function(records) {
   Bar.insert ({
     record: record
   });
 });
```

For now it's crude but that aside - I've heard using forEach is preferred for performance. Is that the general consensus and any thoughts on how to streamline this and implement such a loop in this instance?

Comment: this is a rather easy task. Please show us the code that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in case it's helpful to someone else in the future - here's where this netted out

```
fooArray.forEach(function(item) {
  Bar.insert({
    _id: item.id,
    description: description,
  }); 
 });
```